# Existence of double integrals in general

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

While reading about double integrals on internet I was unable to understand fully the meaning of below lines.It would be extremely helpful if somebody could explain me below lines with some examples like where double integral exists in case of not too discontinous functions.

> The double integral of the function  $z=f(x,y)$ exists provided that the function  $f$ is not too discontinuous. If the function is bounded and continuous over $R$ except on a finite number of smooth curves, then the double integral exists and we say that $f$
> is integrable over $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is just that there are some functions that you cannot integrate. For real functions of one variable, a classic example is the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\text{ is rational,}\\ 1 & x\text{ is irrational.}\end{cases}$$ If you try and compute the usual Riemann sum definition of the integral for this function over any interval, the upper and lower sums will never converge to each other (the lower sum will always be $0$ while the upper sum will always be $1$). The reason this happens is that $f$ is a very discontinuous function. In fact $f$ is discontinuous at every point, so one has no hope of integrating it. Similar examples can be constructed in two variables, such as $$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x\text{ or } y \text{ is rational,}\\ 1 & x\text{ and } y \text{ are both irrational.}\end{cases}$$ Your book is giving a sufficient (although not necessary) condition to get rid of problem functions like $f$ and $g$ for which the Riemann sums do not converge. Intuitively you can think of this statement as being "$f$ can be integrated so long as its graph (in $\mathbb R^3$) is made up of a finite number of pieces, each of which is sufficiently well behaved."

Answer (score 1):

The double integral actually exists as soon as $f$ is bounded and measurable. I guess that your reference did not want to go into the definition of measurability.

Let us denote by $C$ the sets of all these smooth curves. Then this is a negligible set with respect to the Lebesgue measure so if $f$ is continuous on the complement of $C$, and whatever values $f$ assumes on $C$ (assuming $f$ is bounded on $R$ and the domain $R$ of integration is also bounded), then $f$ is measurable and the integral is well-defined and finite.

Comment: Yes, this is for the Lebesgue integral. It also work for the Riemann integral because a bounded function is Riemann integrable if its set of discontinuities is negligible. I am assuming here that $C$ is closed.